# Ellipses for groups on PCA from DESeq2

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca, ellipse

I'd like to add in ellipses around my three groups (based on the variable "outcome") on the following plot. Note that vsd is a DESeq2 object with the factors outcome and batch:

```
pcaData <- plotPCA(vsd, intgroup=c("outcome", "batch"), returnData=TRUE)
percentVar <- round(100 * attr(pcaData, "percentVar"))
ggplot(pcaData, aes(PC1, PC2, color=outcome, shape=batch)) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  xlab(paste0("PC1: ",percentVar[1],"% variance")) +
  ylab(paste0("PC2: ",percentVar[2],"% variance")) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=rownames(coldata_WM_D56C)),hjust=.5, vjust=-.8, size=3) +
  geom_density2d(alpha=.5) +
  coord_fixed()
```

[image: PCA]

I tried adding an ellipse, thinking it would inherit aesthetics from the top but it tried to make an ellipse for each point.

```
stat_ellipse() +
```

> Too few points to calculate an ellipse
>
> geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
>
> Computation failed in `stat_density2d()`: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
> dput(pcaData)
structure(list(PC1 = c(-15.646673151638, -4.21111051849254, 13.1215703467274, 
-6.5477433859415, -3.22129766721873, 4.59321517871152, 1.84089686598042, 
37.8415172383233, 40.9996810499267, 37.6089348653721, -24.5520575763498, 
-46.5840253031228, -4.01498554781508, -31.227922394463), PC2 = c(31.2712754127142, 
5.89621557021357, -10.2425538634254, -3.44497747426626, 2.21504480008043, 
0.315695833259479, -4.66467589267529, -4.27504355920903, -1.08666029542243, 
-2.69753368235982, 5.89767436709778, -24.2836532766506, 4.43980653642228, 
0.659385524221137), group = structure(c(4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 
8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L), .Label = c("ctrl : 1", "ctrl : 2", 
"ctrl : 3", "non : 1", "non : 2", "non : 3", "preg : 1", "preg : 2", 
"preg : 3"), class = "factor"), outcome = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("preg", 
"non", "ctrl"), class = "factor"), batch = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor"), name = structure(1:14, .Label = c("D5-R-N-1", 
"D5-R-N-2", "D5-R-N-3", "D5-R-P-1", "D5-R-P-2", "D5-Z-N-1", "D5-Z-P-1", 
"D6-C-T-1", "D6-C-T-2", "D6-C-T-3", "D6-Z-N-1", "D6-Z-P-1", "D6-Z-P-2", 
"D6-Z-P-3"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("PC1", "PC2", "group", 
"outcome", "batch", "name"), row.names = c("D5-R-N-1", "D5-R-N-2", 
"D5-R-N-3", "D5-R-P-1", "D5-R-P-2", "D5-Z-N-1", "D5-Z-P-1", "D6-C-T-1", 
"D6-C-T-2", "D6-C-T-3", "D6-Z-N-1", "D6-Z-P-1", "D6-Z-P-2", "D6-Z-P-3"
), class = "data.frame", percentVar = c(0.47709343625754, 0.0990361123451665
))
```

As Maurits Evers suggests, I've added a group aes, which only drew ellipses for 2 of 3 outcome types.
[image]

Comment: Please `dput(pcaData)`.

Comment: Your example is still not reproducible and self-consistent :`coldata_WM_D56C` is not defined anywhere. Either way, the plot based on my solution is as expected. **You can't calculate/draw a confidence ellipse with only 3 points.** Not sure what you expect. You can find details in `?stat_ellipse`, which links to `car::ellipse` and Fox and Weisberg's "An R Companion to Applied Regression".

Comment: I didn't realize you need >3 points to calculate an ellipse, so thank you for that information and the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't provide any sample data, here is an example using the `faithful` data.

The key is to add a `group` aesthetic.

```
require(ggplot2);

# Generate sample data
df <- faithful[1:10, ];
df$batch <- as.factor(rep(1:5, each = 2));

# This will throw a similar error/warning to yours
#ggplot(df, aes(waiting, eruptions, color = eruptions > 3, shape = batch)) + geom_point() + stat_ellipse();

# Add a group aesthetic and it works
ggplot(df, aes(waiting, eruptions, color = eruptions > 3, shape = batch, group = eruptions > 3)) + geom_point() + stat_ellipse();
```

[image]

So in your case, try adding `aes(..., group = outcome)`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This almost worked, but only for two of three groups. I've added dput() above, and attached an updated graph with your suggestions.

Comment: Yes, that's as expected. Confidence ellipses can only be drawn for >3 points. See my comment to the original question.